# Iterate through Python Flask/Jinja2 adjacency list

Tags: python, recursion, flask, jinja2, adjacency-list

I'm trying to print out a list of nested comments using the Jinja2 recursive for loop. The problem I have is that after printing out a full nested branch, it starts again from one of the nested children and draws another list from there.

I would like to find a way to skip an iteration if it was already printed before.

I have the following Flask model defined:

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    """Class containing comments to a post"""

    __tablename__ = "comment"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(255))

    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('comment.id'))
    children = db.relationship("Comment")

    def __init__(self, body=None, parent_id=None):
        self.body = body
        self.parent_id = parent_id
```

This loads up a few nested comments:

```
comment = Comment(body="First Comment")
db.session.add(comment)
db.session.commit()

comment2 = Comment(body="Nested with First Comment", parent_id=comment.id)

db.session.add(comment2)
db.session.commit()

comment3 = Comment(body="Also nested with First Comment", parent_id=comment.id)
comment4 = Comment(body="Nested with the fist nested comment", parent_id=comment2.id)

db.session.add(comment3)
db.session.add(comment4)
db.session.commit()
```

Here's the relevant Jinja2 template:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="media-list">
    <li class="media">
      {%- for comment in user.musician.comments recursive %}
      <div class="media">
        <span class="pull-left">
                            {{ comment.author.name }} said:
                        </span>
        <div class="media-body">
          <p>{{comment.body }}</p>
          {% if comment.children %}
          <!-- Children starts here -->
          {{ loop(comment.children) }}
          <!-- end of child -->
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your initial query looks something like

```
comments = Comment.query.all()  # perhaps there's an order_by
```

This returns a query set with all of the comments in it, even those that are children. What you really want is only those comments that aren't children of other comments.

```
comments = Comment.query.filter(Comment.parent_id == None)  # same order_by goes here
```